# Execute programs without specifying full path?

Tags: java, process, path

When using Java and the ProcessBuilder, is there a way to execute e.g. "diskpart" without specifying it's full absolute path (C:\Windows\system32\diskpart.exe)? Especially it might happen that the path changes, e.g. maybe in future it's a 64-bit program... Any chance to tell ProcessBuilder to consider the PATH variable? Thanks!

Comment: On Linux you can run `/usr/bin/env your-command`. Maybe there is `env` for windows too?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you'd be able to achieve thisisto parse the `PATH` variable yourself, using `File.exist` to determine if the program existed at the end of each path element.

You'd probably also need to supply some well known path locations, such `%WINDIR%`

Comment: %WinDir% is explicitly included in %PATH%, so it doesn't need extra handling.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thank you for the the clarification, I (obviously) wasn't aware of that